# Mongo failing to deserialize class with enums

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have this enum:

```
public enum EventType
    {
        Regular = 1,
        Error = 2,
        AccessDenied = 3,
        Warning = 4,
        Maintenance = 5,
        CustomMade = 6
    }
```

I have the following class:

```
[DataContract]
    public class Event : IEvent
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "eventType", IsRequired = true)]
        public EventType EventType { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "occuringDate", IsRequired = true)]
        public DateTime OccuringDate { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "physicalServerId", IsRequired = true)]
        public string PhysicalServerId { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "text", IsRequired = true)]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "systemIds", IsRequired = true)]
        public ICollection<string> SystemIds { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "_id", IsRequired = true)]
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
```

And when I insert it into my mongo collection I get the following object (in mongo):

```
{ "_id" : "1", "eventType" : 1, "occuringDate" : "2014-02-12T20:04:20.4328247+02
:00", "physicalServerId" : "10", "text" : "User has logged in successfully.", "s
ystemIds" : [  "1",  "3" ], "details" : "userId: 2" }
```

Now, when I try to read the the object like this:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);
MongoServer mongoServer = mongoClient.GetServer();
this.db = mongoServer.GetDatabase("eventsLog");
eventsCollection = this.db.GetCollection<Event>("eventsLog");
eventsCollection.Exists();
this.eventsCollection.FindAll().SetSkip((int)(page * perPage)).SetLimit((int)perPage).ToList();
```

I get an exception: `Element 'eventType' does not match any field or property of class LogAggregation.PublicLibrary.Models.Event.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you add that field after the fact? Are some document including them and some not? If thats the case you need to tell BSON serializer that some elements might not exist and thats ok. Add the [BsonIgnoreExtraElements] to your class.

Comment: @Matt Nope, all elements were there when this was written into mongo

Comment: Have you looked at the  [BsonElement("eventType")]  attribute? I've never used Mongo with the DataContract stuff before.

Comment: That seems to fix the problem (using BsonElement istead of DataMember). Post is an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the BsonAttributes to control serialization/deserialization overrides

```
 [BsonElement("eventType")]
```

Instead of

```
[DataMember(Name = "eventType", IsRequired = true)]
```